# SQL use AND to find two values in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am new to SQL and have a bit of a problem. I'm trying to

> find the names of any patients in this database that are suffering
>   from both insomnia *and* a cough

(it's for school so don't worry, no real people harmed by my incompetence).

To achieve this I wrote this:

```
 SELECT patientName 
   FROM Patient 
  WHERE patientID IN (SELECT patientID 
                        FROM Suffers 
                       WHERE illnessName LIKE '%Insomnia%' 
                         AND illnessName LIKE '%Cough%')
```

When I execute it I get no results though (I've got an *empty* cursor). This is a problem, because I know *there is one* patient in the DB with both those illnesses. What am I doing wrong?

Btw, I *have to use* the `AND` operator here, that seems to be the point of this exercise.

Grateful for any and all help :)

Comment: How many illnesses are listed in one row? Your query is looking for two in one. Perhaps you want the intersection of patients with insomnia and patients with a cough. Aside: `like` with wildcards may match things you don't want, e.g. `'%pain%'` matches `'painter''s elbow'`. Is that a good match?

Comment: Would you be able to provide the DB structure?  As your query is now it makes it sound like you have a [Patients] table and a [Suffers] table with [patientID] as a unique field in [Patients] but not in [Suffers]?

Comment: Will a patient ever have `illnessName = '...Insomnia...Cough...'` or `illnessName = '...Cough...Insomnia...'`.  If not then the record will never ever return a result.

Comment: @Habo No, you are right in that 'painter' would not be a good match. I used the wildcards because I learned it from Khan Academy in which the instructor said it was better because it allowed more flexibility. I see how that might be a problem too now though and shall change it to "=".

Comment: @Eric No, they were entered as two different rows I now realize, so there would be two rows with the same patientID but different values for illnessName. I take it this is why Dmitrys solution worked, since it checks two rows?

Comment: @Heeiman Another issue with `like` is that a leading wildcard, e.g. `'%footy'` prevents the query optimizer from using an index seek. (It may still benefit from an index _scan_.) A trailing or embedded wildcard may still use an index seek to find a suitable starting point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should check `patientID` *twice*; your query edited:

```
 SELECT patientName 
   FROM Patient 
  WHERE patientID IN (SELECT patientID FROM Suffers WHERE illnessName LIKE '%Insomnia%')  
    AND patientID IN (SELECT patientID FROM Suffers WHERE illnessName LIKE '%Cough%')
```

Now, `patientID` belongs to Insomnia **and** Cough `Suffers`

Comment: This solved it and I have learned something new about AND and IN, thank you Dmitry!